# Entityframework 6.02 seed method is not getting called

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am trying entity framework (6.02) code first in my webapi project using visual studio 2012.

Following is the simple model, database context and my custom initalizer to seed data. Now when i press f5 and run my code its not hitting the debugger on seed method and no database is creating for me with the orders i provide in seed method.

```
namespace silverstar.wapi.Models
{
    public class Order
    {
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int TotalItems { get; set; }
        public int ProcessedItems { get; set; }
        public int InProgress { get; set; }
        public decimal Percentage { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

    }

    public class SilverStarContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    }

    public class SilverStarInitalizer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<SilverStarContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(SilverStarContext context)
        {
            var orders = new List<Order> { 

                new Order { OrderId=1, TotalItems=200, InProgress=100, ProcessedItems =100, Percentage=50, Title="fifa 2014"},
                new Order { OrderId=2, TotalItems=400, InProgress=200, ProcessedItems =200, Percentage=50, Title="green soccer 2014"}
            };

            orders.ForEach(o => context.Orders.Add(o));
            context.SaveChanges();

//            base.Seed(context);
        }

    }
}
```

Inside my global.asax.cs file i have following code

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer <SilverStarContext>(new SilverStarInitalizer());

        }
```

Comment: It gets called when you do something(ie, querying) for the first time. Did you try executing a query?

Answer (score 0):

You have to instantiate the DbContext and attempt to use it before the model is built

Comment: you need to use your db context - use it to query the DB for some data  and the model (and subsequently the DB itself) will be built